# Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

**To down voters, I have spent days trying to find a solution to this by testing everything I can find and think of. If its a super simple answer or a duplicate, please point me to it because I haven't found anything about it which has helped. Or give pointers how to improve this question.**

---

In my AppDelegate.m I get the following error when I try to use the color in question and it crashes with the error below:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'+[UIColor xForegroundPrimaryColor]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1daf70518'
```

In AppDelegate.m I'm importing the following file where the colour is declared.

```
#import "UIColor+X.h"
```

Which looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIColor (X)

+ (void)setXBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)bgColor foregroundPrimaryColor:(UIColor *)primaryColor foregroundSecondaryColor:(UIColor *)secondaryColor;
+ (UIColor *)xBackgroundColor;
+ (UIColor *)xForegroundPrimaryColor;
+ (UIColor *)xForegroundSecondaryColor;
@end
```

And it crashes when I try to use it here:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    //Appearance
    [[UIControl appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor xForegroundPrimaryColor]];
    ...
}
```

This file and its brother .m are in a separate project in the same workspace, if that makes a difference?

How come Xcode doesn't complain about this color when building but it doesn't exist when running the app?

This started happening after removing Firebase from the project, before that it didn't have any trouble finding it.

**EDIT**

the color is declared like this in the .m file:

```
+ (UIColor *)xForegroundPrimaryColor {
    if (primaryColor)
        return primaryColor;

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:(17.0/255.0) green:(67.0/255.0) blue:(103.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
}
```

**EDIT2**

I just tried to re-add Firebase again by:

1. adding `pod 'Firebase/Messaging'` to the pod file.
2. did a `pod install`
3. added `@import Firebase` in AppDelegate.m
4. added `[FIRApp configure];` in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

And suddenly the color is recognized again. How could that be?

Comment: Your interface declares a class function `xForegroundPrimaryColor`, but have you actually implemented that function? It won't complain at compile time because the declaration is in the interface. It crashes at runtime because Objective C uses dynamic dispatch and it can't find the code you are referring to.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have edited my answer above.

Comment: That is a function called `tractracForegroundPrimaryColor`, not `xForegroundPrimaryColor`.  Assuming that you just used a different name in the first part of your question, have you checked that the .m file is part of your target?

Comment: @Paulw11, yes, just used a different name for the question. I'm not sure what you mean with .m file being part of my target? Just for as a test I tried adding firebase again and suddenly it works. Any idea how that could be? Added an edit.

Comment: I am not sure why adding the Firebase pod would change things, but what I was referring to is the target memberships in the file properties inspector;  double check that the .m file is associated (has a checkbox) for your target in its file inspector properties.